# Play! 2.5 log access to stdout in development

Tags: playframework-2.5

Is there easy way to get development access logs on my console with Play 2.5?
Something I could read as "GET /foo/123 routed to FooController's show action with id=123"?

I've found how to get netty access log ( btw, option play.server.netty.log.wire=true in application.conf doesn't work for me for some reason, but -Dplay.server.netty.log.wire=true does ), but it's too low-level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `logger.xml` file in the conf directory. It should follow logback's file format.

for instance a default configuration could look like :

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="5 seconds">
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%level %logger{15} - %message%n%xException{5}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="play" level="INFO" />
    <logger name="application" level="INFO" />

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

You can then enable loglevels : FATAL, ERROR, WARNING, INFO, DEBUG, TRACE selectively for any package or as a default on the root leve.

This is described in the playframework configuration [configuring logging](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SettingsLogger)

Note that this behaviour was [changed in 2.4.x](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24#Logging) from the previous versions where you could configure loggers through `application.conf`

Once you have logging working you can use the sample logging filter [provided in the documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaHttpFilters) to log all requests to your server.

```
import javax.inject.Inject
import akka.stream.Materializer
import play.api.Logger
import play.api.mvc._
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}

class LoggingFilter @Inject() (implicit val mat: Materializer, ec: ExecutionContext) extends Filter {

  def apply(nextFilter: RequestHeader => Future[Result])
           (requestHeader: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = {

    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis

    nextFilter(requestHeader).map { result =>

      val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis
      val requestTime = endTime - startTime

      Logger.info(s"${requestHeader.method} ${requestHeader.uri} took ${requestTime}ms and returned ${result.header.status}")

      result.withHeaders("Request-Time" -> requestTime.toString)
    }
  }
}
```

you will have to activate it by setting the `play.http.filters`:

```
play.http.filters=com.example.LoggingFilter
```

Comment: Thanks Jean! I've tried this but it gives me no information about how my request is routed, what controler and action called and so on.
For instance in RoR application I always see any request made to the development server. But Play gives me nothing. Even when I set DEBUG level for root logger I see a lot of information about, say, class loading, but no information about requests.

Comment: So looks like there is no way to get it for free. Thanks again!